# how to run Applets on Safari(web browser)

Tags: java

hii every one
good morning
I have created one project on JApplet
it runs successfully on Applet window
but i want to run it on web browsers(Internet explorer , Mozilla firefox, Safari, etc.)
I m using Mac os x and i want to run it on Safari.

Comment: plz tell me what can i do for it

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an html which refers to the applet. Open the html in browser.

Take a look here for the applet tag http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_applet.asp

Comment: yeah i ve used it but it shows code as it is ..its not run my class

Comment: I ve used this code...
<html>...
<title> BUSINESS CARD READER</title>...
<head>.....
</head>....
<body ><center>...

 <applet code = "myClass.class" height= 800 width= 8000 ></applet>...
</center>...
</body>.....
</html>.....

Answer (score 0):

Using Mac OS X, in `/Applications/Utilities` you'll find `Java Preferences.app`. In the `Advanced` tab, you can enable the `Java Console`, which may tell you more about what's wrong when you open your HTML page in a browser.

Also, you can edit your question to add code, etc.

Addendum: You might want to start with a known working [example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html).

Comment: thanks.. i ve made some changes there.. i ve checked show console radio button.. but still its not working

Comment: What is still not working? Show how to do what? You might try the example cited above,